# Unit test to check for unused properties

Tags: c#, regex, unit-testing, reflection, nunit

I have a function that runs through the properties of a class and replaces the keyword between two dollar signs with the same name from a template.

An example of a class:

```
public class FeedMessageData : IMailObject
{
    public string Username { get; private set;}
    public string SubscriptionID { get; private set; }
    public string MessageTime { get; private set; }
    public string Subject { get; private set; }

    public FeedMessageData(string username, string subscriptionID, DateTime messageTime)
    {
        this.Username = username;
        this.SubscriptionID = subscriptionID;
        this.MessageTime = messageTime.ToShortDateString();

        this.Subject = "Feed " + DateTime.Now + " - SubscriptionID: " + this.SubscriptionID;
    }
}
```

And this is the function to replace the template with the properties:

```cs
private string mergeTemplate(string template, IMailObject mailObject)
{
    Regex parser = new Regex(@"\$(?:(?<operation>[\w\-\,\.]+) ){0,1}(?<value>[\w\-\,\.]+)\$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    var matches = parser.Matches(template).Cast<Match>().Reverse();
    foreach (var match in matches)
    {
        string operation = match.Groups["operation"].Value;
        string value = match.Groups["value"].Value;

        var propertyInfo = mailObject.GetType().GetProperty(value);
        if (propertyInfo == null)
            throw new TillitException(String.Format("Could not find '{0}' in object of type '{1}'.", value, mailObject));

        object dataValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(mailObject, null);

        template = template.Remove(match.Index, match.Length).Insert(match.Index, dataValue.ToString());
    }
    return template;
}
```

I'm looking to create a unit test that writes to the console, possible properties that aren't utilized in the template. An example would be if there wasn't a $SubscriptionID$ in the template. I've tried using PropertyInfo, which gives me the properties of the class, but how do I then use this information to check if they have already been used in the template?

Comment: Can you indicate what you have tried and where you faced a particular problem. From your description, you are more or less looking for someone to write the code for you not help u solve a problem. Off the top of my head Unit test platforms e.g. XUnit offer verification mechanisms where you can verify whether a property/method has been called. Have you tried exploring such options?

Comment: @gerryc.inc I can see how the wording makes it seem like I just want the code written for me, but then I won't learn a thing. What I have tried is to get the properties being used via PropertyInfo, but once I have these, then I'm not certain how I should check if the value is used in the template. The other idea I've been trying is to use Regex to check for words between dollar signs, but that only gave me the words from the template, which I already have a test for.

Comment: check my answer for an example using Moq. I hope it should get you started on the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moq (https://github.com/moq/moq4/wiki) provides ways to verify property/method access.
Follow the tutorials on [this link](http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/08/03/moq-working-with-setupget-verifyget-setupset-verifyset-setupproperty/) for more details. To verify that your properties are being consumed in your template, you can make use of the `VerifyGet` method, an example below:

```
[Fact]
public void VerifyAllPropertiesHaveBeenConsumedInTemplate()
{
    var mockMailObject = new Mock<IMailObject>();
    var template = "yourTemplateOrMethodThatReturnsYourTemplate";

    var result = mergeTemplate(template, mockMailObject.Object);

    mockMailObject.VerifyGet(m => m.Username, Times.Once);
    mockMailObject.VerifyGet(m => m.SubscriptionID, Times.Once);
    mockMailObject.VerifyGet(m => m.MessageTime, Times.Once);
    mockMailObject.VerifyGet(m => m.Subject, Times.Once);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped alot. What i was working on worked in a sense, but i wasnt able to check it against the template itself

Comment: Happy to help. Mind marking as answer if you are satisfied?